# Loop not exiting as expected

Tags: c, scanf

I expected this program to stop the loop when i press enter button but instead the terminal become blank and do not show anything. Whats wrong with this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int c;
   printf("Enter a char(To exit loop press enter)");
   for(c=' ';c!='\n';)
   {
       scanf("%d",&c);

       putchar(c);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try entering '61' and hitting return.

Comment: Make sure your assumptions are correct, and that `scanf` will put a newline character into `c`, when the format specifier is specifically scanning for an `int`.

Comment: Vague memory from years and years ago:  You have unexpected input in the buffer, so `scanf` is reading nothing infinitely (or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, see following fixes :-

```
   char c ; // Use a char
   char  ch;
   printf("Enter a char(To exit loop press enter)");
   scanf("%c",&c);
   for(;c!='\n';)
   {
     //Eat up the trailing newline from previous input

     while(( ch =getchar() ) != '\n' && (ch != EOF ));            

      scanf("%c",&c);

       putchar(c);
   }
```

Comment: @POW this is working but i do not understand the code. I am new to it.

Comment: @ChandrakantSingh - Then study the language.  What you don't understand is very elementary and you will come to understand it by reading the first chapter of any C textbook.  Asking people on SO to solve your problems is not a good way to learn.

Comment: @CareyGregory you are right. I am not using people to solve my pbm,just attempting to learn it. Thanks

Comment: @ChandrakantSingh  well with `scanf` you'll get trailing newline, this you need to remove , which is done by `getchar` in a `while` loop, which also checks for `EOF`. So here first `scanf` a `char` now check if its not equal to newline, remove the newline & repeated this until you get newline

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `scanf()` for a char, you need to use `%c`, not `%d`, with a char variable:

```
char c;
scanf("%c",&c);
```

Comment: This is not the **only** problem